# Any presentation style editor available?

Tags: presentation, editor, powerpoint

I'm building a presentation style web application that lets users add shapes, charts, tables, images on a slide. Something like [Ludus.one](https://Ludus.one). Before I create it from scratch I wanted to know if there's any libraries, technology I can make use of?

There seems to be several Microsoft Word style products available to purchase which can be integrated into other applications, like [ckeditor.com](https://ckeditor.com)